# How can I delete duplcation from my joined tables?

Tags: sql, join, select, datatables, duplicates

I would like to know how I can get rid of the duplicates due to my joins between the different please?

Here is my request:

```
SELECT
T_OF.OFID, T_OF.OFDateDPrev, T_OF.OFDateFPrev,
DATEDIFF (second, T_OF.OFDateDPrev, OFDateFPrev) AS DureePrevSec,
T_OF.OFDateDReelle,
T_OF.OFDateFReelle,
DATEDIFF (second, T_OF.OFDateDReelle, OFDateFReelle) AS DureeRelleSec,
T_OF.OFEtat,
T_OF.OFDateState,
T_Sequence_phase_OF.SeqPhaseNom,
T_OF.OFQtyPrev,
T_OF.OFQtyReal,
T_OF.ArtID,
T_OF.UnitID,
T_OF_Nomenclature.OFNomQty,
T_OF.LineID,
T_OF_User.OFUserID,
T_Sequence_phase_OF.SeqPhaseId,
T_Sequence_phase_OF.SeqId,
T_Sequence_phase_OF.SeqPhaseEtat,
T_Sequence_phase_OF.SeqPhaseDateEtat,
T_Sequence_phase_OF.SeqPhaseDateDebut,
T_Sequence_phase_OF.SeqPhaseDateEnd
INTO T_tracing2
FROM T_OF
INNER JOIN T_OF_Nomenclature
ON T_OF.OFID = T_OF_Nomenclature.OFID

INNER JOIN T_OF_User
ON T_OF_User.OFID = T_OF.OFID
INNER JOIN T_Sequence_phase_OF
On T_Sequence_phase_OF.OFId = T_OF.OFID
ALTER TABLE T_tracing2 ADD OFUserPrevID VARCHAR (200) DEFAULT '1'
ALTER TABLE T_tracing2 ADD LineID VARCHAR (200) DEFAULT '100'
ALTER TABLE T_tracing2 ADD ArtPrevID VARCHAR (200) DEFAULT '245'
```

The duplicates are in the SeqPhaseNom columns because I made 3 joins suddenly this field is repeated 3 times in my table.

I give an example of tables:
T_OF table:

```
T_OF        
OFID    OFDateDPrev OFDateFPrev
159     2019-12-17 16:30:00.000 2019-12-19 00:00:00.000
160     2019-12-19 16:38:36.743 2019-12-19 17:38:36.743
161     2019-12-19 00:00:00.000 2019-12-19 08:00:00.000
162     2020-01-15 00:00:00.000 2020-01-16 00:00:00.000
163     2020-01-15 12:22:18.090 2020-01-15 13:22:18.090
164     2020-01-15 12:31:20.053 2020-01-15 13:31:20.053
165     2020-01-15 13:45:22.467 2020-01-15 14:45:22.467
166     2020-01-16 08:03:00.000 2020-01-16 08:06:00.000
```

T_Sequence_Phase_OF table:

```
T_Sequence_Phase_OF             
OFId    SeqPhaseNom SeqPhaseId  SeqPhaseEtat    SeqPhaseDateDebut
161     Debut       1           170 2019-12-19 16:51:46.523
161     Ecriture    2           140 2019-12-19 16:51:47.323
164     Debut       3           170 2020-01-15 12:31:54.617
164     Boucle Flacon4          170 2020-01-15 12:31:55.587
164     Stockage    5           160 2020-01-15 12:31:56.183
165     Debut       6           170 2020-01-15 13:45:32.307
165 Boucle Flacon   7           170 2020-01-15 13:45:32.823
165 Stockage        8           170 2020-01-15 13:45:33.407
165 Remplissage     9           170 2020-01-15 14:03:58.283
165 Bouchonnage     10          170 2020-01-15 14:04:03.350
165 Destockage      11          170 2020-01-15 14:04:07.383
165 Retour boucle flacon    14  170 2020-01-15 14:04:14.220
165 Boucle Flacon   15          170 2020-01-15 14:04:14.917
165 Stockage        16          170 2020-01-15 14:04:15.603
165 Remplissage     17          170 2020-01-15 14:05:37.443
165 Bouchonnage     18          170 2020-01-15 14:05:41.340
```

T_OF_user

```
T_Users 
OFId    OFUserID
161     108
162     109
162     110
163     111
164     112
165     113
```

T_ Nomenclature table:

```
T_Nomenclature  
OFId    OFNomQty
159     3.0000
162     40.0000
162     4.0000
162     4.0000
163     3.0000
163     3.0000
163     3.0000
164     40.0000
164     4.0000
164     4.0000
```

The result of this query is :

```
OFID OFDateDPrev OFDateFPrev SeqPhaseNom
164 2020-01-15  2020-01-15  Debut
164 2020-01-15  2020-01-15  Debut
164 2020-01-15  2020-01-15  Debut
164 2020-01-15  2020-01-15  Boucle Flacon
164 2020-01-15  2020-01-15  Boucle Flacon
164 2020-01-15  2020-01-15  Boucle Flacon
164 2020-01-15  2020-01-15  Stockage
164 2020-01-15  2020-01-15  Stockage
164 2020-01-15  2020-01-15  Stockage 
165 2020-01-15  2020-01-16  Debut
165 2020-01-15  2020-01-15  Debut
165 2020-01-15  2020-01-15  Debut
165 2020-01-15  2020-01-15  Boucle Flacon
165 2020-01-15  2020-01-15  Boucle Flacon
165 2020-01-15  2020-01-15  Boucle Flacon
.....
```

We have Three time the same SeqPhaseNom because I carried out three joins

And that what I want getting as result is that:

```
OFID OFDateDPrev OFDateFPrev SeqPhaseNom
164  2020-01-15     2020-01-15  Debut
164  2020-01-15     2020-01-15  Boucle Flacon
164  2020-01-15     2020-01-15  Stockage
165  2020-01-15     2020-01-15  Debut
165  2020-01-15     2020-01-15  Boucle Flacon
....
```

Maybe my request is not well made. Maybe I have to use several nested SELECT but I dont know how ?

Any help please ?

Comment: Don't repost [your closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60566765/3404097), edit the original question. Act on the comments. Then wait for it to be voted open after it is improved enough.

Comment: Your query involves 4 tables. At least one relation generates duplicates. You can break the queries in smaller pieces, adding the join one by one and stop when duplicates appear.

Answer (score 0):

maybe an easy

"Select distinct * from TABLE"

can help you.

Thank you.